# How to create exact same header and footer navigation panel (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

I current have a navigation panel (ASP.NET) for a online that has some common buttons (next, back, reset, submit etc.). I also have some logic written (server side in C#) that handles changing the currently visible panel and such.

I would prefer to have the navigation panel to appear at the top and bottom of the page, without having to write additional logic for those buttons, as if I want to change functionality I have to change it in two places, instead of one.

Comment: So you want us to send you the zip file? maybe we'll give you a link to the server with the application running?

Answer (score 2):

I would write an ASP.NET [Web User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which allows you to encapsulate that functionality within a reusable control which you can place one or more times on the page.  This sounds like it would meet your needs and allow you to use that control across not only multiple locations within a single form, but across more than one web form if you find you need to do that in the future.

Comment: I agree with Charles. I use Server Controls all the time in html pages. You can put them where ever you want.